# Do horizontal and vertical dead pixels on some of the bands of a hyper-spectral image affect the accuracy of the model?

Tags: image-segmentation

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. It should be here according to questions I saw.

I am working of PRISMA Earth Observation images which consist of tens of spectral bands. My final goal is to segment the clouds in these images using Unet model.

My intention is to label them to train on my segmentation model, but there are some defections on some random bands. Totally, there are 63 bands, so each pixel is represented by 63 different bands. Some of them are dead. These dead pixel lines, are not always the same place or line. Also there are some bands in which there are no defection. I don't have a distribution of these defections, but can say 5-10 out of 63 bands might be dead for some pixels.

It would be super nice if I can pre-process them to get rid of these pixels, although I don't know how to do this, and that could take a long time. I have also questions which make me think of if it is necessary or smart to do so.

My first question is; Do these totally random horizontal and vertical lines affect the accuracy of my segmentation model? Should I label ignoring these lines or not?

Secondly, won't this pre-processing change the image? These are geolocation data and I don't want to spoil the data when I am trying to make them look better. Is there any way to achieve to get rid of these lines without "harm" the image?

[image: An example RGB visualization of one of the images]

[image: A false color visualization of the same image]

Comment: The approach will depend on your segmentation procedure and the statistical nature of these defects. Could you expand on those details a little? For instance, how are the bands chosen for defects and how many bands might be involved at any given pixel? Do they have defects along common lines or different lines? Can your segmentation procedure handle missing values? It's probably based on local neighborhoods, but how large are those neighborhoods and of what shapes? Also, it's unclear why you are worried about harming the image: after segmentation you can always return to the original image.

Comment: I have edited my question with more details about the dead pixel lines and the model. I don't worry about harming the image, I worry about if these dead pixels get the accuracy down. I want to learn how to make assessments with respect to segmentation or any other image classification task. Please provide me with feedback if there are still vague points in my question.